# Puzzling "'tuple' object does not support item assignment" error

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
>>> t = ([],)
>>> t[0].extend([12, 34])
>>> t
([12, 34],)
>>> t[0] += [56, 78]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t
([12, 34, 56, 78],)
>>>
```

I understand that tuples are immutable, but *the item in the LHS is not a tuple!*  (The fact that the intended assignment in fact succeeded, the error message notwithstanding, makes the whole scenario only more bizarre.)

Why is this behavior not considered a bug?

Comment: Why do people always come to SO with a question before going to the Python FAQ with it? In the FAQ, you will get an answer that's been reasoned over, painstakingly written, and vetted by multiple core developers, and has stood the test of time. On SO, you get an answer that someone slaps together in 5 minutes, edits repeatedly for the next 5 minutes, then abandons for the rest of time. Wouldn't you rather have the former?

Comment: @abarnert, because there are an infinite number of ways to ask a question and the google/stackoverflow results catch far more than searching python.org.  SO casts the widest question net and when it fails, asking a question is usually rewarded with a fast response and points.  In many cases other better resources are linked to, so people will be pointed back to the best answer source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
t[0] += [56, 78]
```

is short for

```
t[0] = t[0].__iadd__([56, 78])
```

where `t` is a tuple. The `t[0].__iadd__([56, 78])` part changes the list, but then the result cannot be stored as `t[0]`.

The LHS in Python is always a name, never a value. In every Python expression, the RHS is evaluated to a value and assigned to the name on the LHS. In this case the name `t[0]` cannot be assigned to because `t` is a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented and explained [in the Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works).

For a full discussion, read the FAQ entry. But briefly, the problem is that this code:

```
t[0] += [56, 78]
```

… is equivalent to this:

```
t[0] = t[0].__iadd__([56, 78])
```

The `__iadd__` successfully modifies the `list` in-place, and returns itself; then the assignment raises the exception.

It's [not considered a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue11562), because it's an unavoidable consequence of how `+=`, `list.__iadd__`, and `tuple` all work. While it's not obvious to anyone who doesn't understand those three things, any attempt to change things would be much more non-obvious to anyone who *did* understand (and would likely break a lot of other, more important, cases).